Can't write to table due to multixact “members” limit exceeded (SQLSTATE 54000) after heavy inserts
The database was under sustained high load of inserts into a specific table for several hours.
At some point, all inserts to that table (and some updates I tried to another table) fail with the following error:
multixact “members” limit exceeded (SQLSTATE 54000)

There was also the following detail:
This command would create a multixact with 2 members, but the remaining space is only enough for 0 members.

And the hint:
Execute a database-wide VACUUM in database with OID ***** with reduced vacuum_multixact_freeze_min_age and vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age settings.

I'm trying to solve this issue by VACUUM; on the entire database which takes a very long time, since that was the suggestion online and also what was hinted by the DB on failed operations.
I'd very much like to better understand this situation and the actual cause.
How should this issue actually be solve it how should I avoid it in the future?
